# Is there any way to determine attribute is select/choice in django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

Currently implementing searchbox which provides two interface - textbox if required input is not normalized, and dropdown if required input is normalized and is defined with choices param in model, and select class in form.
Current model(partial):
`id = models.CharField(args)
 submitter = models.CharField(args)
 experiment_type = models.CharField(args, choices=<tuple with choices>)`
Current form.Meta.widgets for model above:
`'id': TextInput(attrs={'id':'exp_id', readonly: ''})
 'experiment_type': Select(attrs={'id': 'experiment_type', required=''})`

I've currently found that I can retrieve each fields' html snippet by doing str(field), for field in form, and with beautifulsoup or other html parsing library I can find input type(is text field or dropdown(select)), and option values for dropdown.
But it seems too compilcated, and I'm currently guessing that there might be 
some way django provides to determine such things.
Looking forward, and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've added some code snippet, hope it'll help

Comment: Sam you should use modelforms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/